# Retrieve Values of Multiple Arrays with just an index

Tags: ios, arrays, function, swift3, xcode8

So I am trying to retrieve the value of multiple arrays given an index. So for example if I have three arrays 'one', 'two' and 'three' which have 12 values. My function getEvents(monthIndex: 0) will return: one[0], two[0], and three[0] in one array called 'day1'. Now I attempted it however since there are 12 values inside each array already, it returns 36 values instead of three. I tried to do a breakpoint but I have no luck as to understand where it's going wrong. I'm sure I'm close but I think I need some tips so here I am.

Here's what I have so far:

```
func getEvents (monthIndex: Int)-> [String] {
    var day1: [String] = []

    arrays = [one, two, three]

    for array in arrays {
        for days in array {
            day1.append(array[monthIndex])
        }
    }
    return day1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing your code will be like this

```
func getEvents (monthIndex: Int)-> [String] {
    var day1: [String] = []

    arrays = [one, two, three]

    for array in arrays {
         day1.append(array[monthIndex])
    }
    return day1
}
```

But better is this

**In one line**

```
func getEvents (monthIndex: Int)-> [String] {
        arrays = [one, two, three]
        return arrays.map({$0[monthIndex]})
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Lol. Man. That's how I know I'm burnt out! Did not even catch that. Good catch. Fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming you did it for clarification but no need to return "var days", rather just return arrays.map({$0[monthIndex]}).

Comment: @insolence you are right is a typo, i will update lol, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Thank you!